# How do I get a list of classes with their owner's id attached?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I can get a list of users by calling `/education/users`, and a list of classes through `/education/classes`; but is there a way of getting the classes with the foreign key included?

So far the only way I've found to do this is by using `/education/users/{id}/classes`, but I don't want to have to call that for every user.

A sample of what's being returned by the aforementioned endpoints:

`/education/users`:

```php
{
    "surname"=>"Wyatt", 
    "usageLocation"=>"CA", 
    "userPrincipalName"=>"DWyatt@fairviewss.onmicrosoft.com", 
    "userType"=>"Member", 
    "middleName"=>"Robert", 
    "externalSource"=>"sis", 
    "primaryRole"=>"teacher", 
    "teacher"=>{
        "teacherNumber"=>"105", 
        "externalId"=>"14005"
    }
}
```

`education/classes`:

```php
{
    "id"=>"6981f588-c561-4156-8eb9-d733360e3d76", 
    "description"=>"Super science", 
    "displayName"=>"Science", 
    "mailNickname"=>"Science"
}, 
{
    "id"=>"788ee4cd-82a4-4c39-a9e5-0ce6c1877a09", 
    "description"=>"Math", 
    "displayName"=>"Math", 
    "mailNickname"=>"Math"
}, 
{
    "id"=>"9c4af1e4-98eb-4cb0-9288-95b5defe4579", 
    "description"=>nil, 
    "displayName"=>"Science - Biology 1", 
    "mailNickname"=>"Section_11018", 
    "classCode"=>"11018", 
    "externalName"=>"Science - Biology 1", 
    "externalId"=>"11018", 
    "externalSource"=>"sis", 
    "term"=>{
        "externalId"=>"12000", 
        "startDate"=>"2017-07-01", 
        "endDate"=>"2018-06-30", 
        "displayName"=>"SY1516"
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm getting something wrong, I'm just not sure what.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "foreign key included"?

Comment: I mean the owner of a class. So the teacher's id, or whatever is linking a class to a teacher. I'm looking for a way to get all the teachers (which I have) and all the classes, then display a teacher's information, along with their classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the teachers in the list of classes using `$expand=teachers`:

```
/v1.0/education/classes?$expand=teachers
```

If you [execute this in Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=education/classes?$expand=teachers&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com), you'll get a collection of `class` objects including the teachers associated with each class:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#education/classes",
    "value": [{
            "id": "ef18b112-d6dc-4b56-8cee-85f82dbe8a7d",
            "description": "Presentation Skills 101 training",
            "displayName": "Presentation Skills 101",
            "mailNickname": "PresentationSkills101",
            "teachers@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#education/classes('ef18b112-d6dc-4b56-8cee-85f82dbe8a7d')/users",
            "teachers": [{
                "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
                "accountEnabled": true,
                "displayName": "Megan Bowen",
                "givenName": "Megan",
                "surname": "Bowen",
                "userPrincipalName": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
                "userType": "Member",
                "primaryRole": "teacher"
            }]
        }
    }
    ...
```